# Value is out of Range Exception While setting ResourceDictionary Source to CustomControl's generic.XAML

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, custom-controls

I have a custom Control which contains the generic.xaml inside the Themes folder. I have set the build action to Resource.

Now from App.xaml I am setting the reference to the DLL by using :

```
xmlns:localFolder="clr-namespace:customControl;assembly=customControl"
```

After the reference is set I am trying to Merge the Resource dictionary in my App.xaml as follow:

```
<Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="localFolder;component/Themes/generic.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

But while running my application  I am getting the following `XAMLParseException`:

```
Attribute localFolder;component/Themes/generic.xaml value is out of range. [Line: 16 Position: 44]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Source` should be in the `Uri` format - `/assembly-name;component/path-to-resource`. You can't define an XML namespace with `xmlns:localFolder="..."` and then use it in the URI string. Here is [some reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) on the accepted formats.